# Removing detergent residue from glassware

Tags: glassware, head

Last night, after moving some heavy stones around, I poured myself a nice Berliner Weisse (style) into a glass I don't use regularly.  Initially there was a nice head on it but to my disappointment it broke down in a matter of seconds.  I'm pretty certain this was a result of detergent residue in the glass.

I take pains to hand wash my beer glasses without detergent but some members of my household are not always cognizant of the damage this causes.  Once the detergent residue is on the glass, is there any method that can remove it?  I think that in the past I've found that wiping firmly and rinsing will eventually remove it but that means many flat beers along the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, washing and rinsing properly first time should mean this problem doesn't happen.

If it does, vinegar is an excellent residue remover.

- Rinse the glass fully in clean water (no soap).
- Rub the glass with a small sponge soaked in vinegar
- Rinse again

That should solve the problem.